# Implicit declaration of function "..." is invalid in C99?

Tags: objective-c, function-calls

I'm trying to declare a function within another function. So here's part of my code:
ViewController.m

```
- (void)updatedisplay{
    [_displayText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter]];

}

- (IBAction)minus1:(id)sender {
    counter--;
    updatedisplay();
}
```

ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)minus1:(id)sender;
- (void)updatedisplay;
```

Which returned me the error of "Implicit declaration of function "..." is invalid in C99".

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGevK.png

I've found that people have encountered similar problem, but as a newbie I didn't really know what to do next. Thanks for your help! :)

[Implicit declaration of function '...' is invalid on C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583497/implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-on-c99)

Comment: first learn some basic things related to objective see after that you can implement programs..http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not declaring a `function`; but a `instance method`, so to call it you must send it as a message to `self`;

`[self updatedisplay];`

EDIT

As @rmaddy pointed out (thanks for that) it is declared as instance method not class method. To make the things clear;

`- (return_type)instance_method_name....` is called via 'self' or pointer to object instance.
 `+ (return_type)class_method_name....` is called directly on the class (static).

Comment: `updatedisplay` is declared as an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: should I still use 'self' even if the function has parameters? like gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);

Answer (score 7):

Problem

```
updatedisplay();
```

solution

```
[self updatedisplay];
```

cause

```
- (void)updatedisplay;
```

is a class method available for that class.So you have to call from the class to have the method available for you.

Answer (score 4):

That is because you defined your function as a instance method, not a function.

So use it like

```
- (IBAction)minus1:(id)sender {
    counter--;
    [self updatedisplay]; // Change this line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

write this way :

```
[self updatedisplay];
```